# Can I remove the span element with sr-only class in Bootstrap-vue table?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

Here's an example of Bootstrap-vue table:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-table striped hover :items="items" :fields="fields"></b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        // Note 'isActive' is left out and will not appear in the rendered table
        fields: [
          {
            key: 'last_name',
            sortable: true
          },
          {
            key: 'first_name',
            sortable: false
          },
          {
            key: 'age',
            label: 'Person age',
            sortable: true,
            // Variant applies to the whole column, including the header and footer
            variant: 'danger'
          }
        ],
        items: [
          { isActive: true, age: 40, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald' },
          { isActive: false, age: 21, first_name: 'Larsen', last_name: 'Shaw' },
          { isActive: false, age: 89, first_name: 'Geneva', last_name: 'Wilson' },
          { isActive: true, age: 38, first_name: 'Jami', last_name: 'Carney' }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

and if open console the element of a thead would be look like:

```
<th role="columnheader" scope="col" tabindex="0" aria-colindex="1" aria-sort="none" class="">
   Last Name
   <span class="sr-only"> (Click to sort Ascending)</span>
</th>
```

Is there any ways I can remove

```
<span class="sr-only"> (Click to sort Ascending)</span>
```

with Bootstrap-vue property itself? If possible I don't want to delete it with JavaScript after it is built. Thanks

Comment: `.sr-only {display: none;}` in css can work for you?

Comment: @AlexBrohshtut It still appears in DOM Tree, yet this solved my problem!! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Why do you want to remove it? It's placed the for people who use screen-readers so they know what to do. Elements with the `sr-only` has styling so that it wont be displayed to normal users, but is still viewable by screen readers.

Comment: @Hiws I'm using clipboard.js try to build a table which can be copied and paste into excel files. I find out words in sr-only would also be copied into it too, and I need to remove it to complete this feature.

Comment: @EasonLin Makes sense. Just thought I'd let you know :)

Comment: perhaps filter the spans out of the copied data, or request a feature in `clicpboard.js` that allows you to filter out elements of certain classes or patterns.

Comment: Or add the style rule dynamically to set `display: none;` on sr-only, just before the copy, and then remove it after the copy is complete.

Answer (score 3):

```
::v-deep .sr-only{display:none !important}
```